# jQuery animating multiple elements performance

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate, animated

i have a site on which i have to animate a "few" elements at the same time. 
when ALL elements finished animating (which i test with `$(:animated) == 1` )
i have an ajax request. everthing works fine for about 120 elements but when it comes to a bigger number of elements, the script is getting to busy and the browser asks me to stop the script :-/ here is my code:

```
$('.wrapper-1, .wrapper-2').animate({
            scrollLeft: 50
        },{
            queue: false, //I thought this would help, has no influence
            complete: function() {
                if($(':animated').length==1){

                        //do fancy stuff and get ajax contents              

                } //END if animated
            }//END scroll animation complete
        });//END animate
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can handle a bigger amount of elements??

THANKS